# How can I access a pointer to an array inside a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I have the following structure

```
typedef struct {
uint8  u8Status;
uint64 u64IeeeAddrRemoteDev;
uint16 u16NwkAddrRemoteDev;
uint8  u8NumAssocDev;
uint8  u8StartIndex;

/* rest of the message is variable Length */
uint16* pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList;
} ZPS_tsAplZdpIeeeAddrRsp;
```

Here `pNwkAddrAssocDevList` is a pointer to a list of 16-bit network addresses.

I am using this following piece of code

```
ZPS_tsAplZdpIeeeAddrRsp p;
/* this structure p is already filled by the system, i just need to access it*/
/* using for loop */
printf("%04x",p.pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList[i]);
```

But I'm not getting the correct value, It returns some memory address.

Can anyone help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you initialized p before accessing it?

Comment: yes, p is allocate by the another program and i have tested other member in structure they are properly assigned but the array is causeing problem.

Comment: The code you have here is correct under the assumption that the memory that pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList points to is correctly allocated, and the index i is within the correct bounds.  Therefore, if this is not producing the results you expected, then we need more information about how the memory was allocated, and what values you are using for i.

Comment: Did you check that `p.u8NumAssocDev` is different than `0`? If this is case is the first value of the array correct?

Comment: You say: "*But I'm not getting the correct value, It returns some memory address.*". What makes you feel that the value is not correct? More importantly: What makes you think it is printing a 'memory addreses'? Have you seen the values contained in the struct in a debugger? Have you access to the code where it is assigned? If yes, then have you seen what is assigned there and know for sure that the values you see are *not* the same as what is assigned there? One final note: How do you know how many values are stored there?

Comment: You said "16-bit network addresses", is this a problem with endianness perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here as pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList is a pointer. You would need to add another variable to the structure to define the length/no of values in pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList, say **int length**. Once you have the length you can access the values of pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList by looping thru.

`for (int i=0; i < p.length; i++) {`

```
    printf("%04x", p->pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList);

    pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList++;
```

`}`

This way you can easily iterate thru the values stored in pu16NwkAddrAssocDevList.